# Different calculations in EXCEL and TERADATA SQL

Tags: excel, teradata

The calculation `select (75/979.86)*979.86` in Teradata SqL gives 78.3888. In excel, it would give 75 simply and that is logically correct. I get it that SQL is rounding off 75/979.86 to 0.08 ie the number of decimal digits in 979.86. And hence the result is different.So, I can simply do (75*979.86)/979.86 instead and get the result.But is there any way to match these exactly maybe by changing data type or rounding off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata rounds after each calculation based on the resulting datatype (Standard SQL compliant), to get the expected reault you can either CAST the 1st operand to a NUMBER (no need to think about precision) and finally back to DECIMAL:

```
Cast((Cast(75 AS NUMBER)/979.86) *979.86 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Ot you rearrange the order of calculation to multiply first and then divide:

```
979.86 * 75 / 979.86
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I did.. We can use something like cast as( number as decimal(18,5)) to convert the data type of numbers to have 5 decimal digits. And then, again use cast as with the number of decimal digits we need our results to be rounded upto which in my case is 2. So, something like this

`select cast((cast(75 as decimal(18,5))/cast(979.86 as decimal(18,5)))*cast(979.86 as decimal(18,5)) as decimal(18,2)) ;`

We can increase the decimal places to increase the precision as much we like but also should be careful for the "numeric overflow" error